# strategy for fitting angle data

Tags: outliers, data-fitting, angle, ransac

I have a set of angles. The distribution could be roughly described as:

- there a are usually several values very close (0.0-1.0 degree apart) to the correct solution
- there are also noisy values being very far from the correct result, even opposite direction

is there a common solution/strategy for such a problem?

For multidimensional data, I would use RANSAC - but I have the impression that it is unusual to apply Ransac on 1-dimensional data. Another problem is computing the mean of an angle. I read some other posts about how to calculate the mean of angles by using vectors, but I just wonder if there isn't a particular fitting solution which deals with both issues already.

Comment: Because this is not a programming related problem, chances are it will be closed pretty soon. You might have better luck asking at math.stackexchange, stats.stackexchange or metaoptimize. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RANSAC even in this case, all the necessary conditions (minimal samples, error of a data point, consensus set) are met. Your minimal sample will be 1 point, a randomly picked angle (although you can try all of them, might be fast enough). Then, all the angles (data points) with error (you can use just absolute distance, modulo 360) less than some threshold (e.g. 1 degree), will be considered as inliers, i.e. within the consensus set.

If you want to play with it a bit more, you can make the results more stable by adding some local optimisation, see e.g.:
*Lebeda, Matas, Chum: Fixing the Locally Optimized RANSAC, BMVC 2012.*

You could try another approaches, e.g. median, or fitting a mixture of Gaussian and uniform distribution, but you would have to deal with the periodicity of the signal somehow, so I guess RANSAC should be your choice.